# How to make pdf (all text as image) to readable pdf (for ADA compliant)?

Tags: pdf, adobe

Here is my situation. I have a pdf that has all text as images from starting page to ending page. Its all good but does not work for ADA compliant when screen reader is used. Nothing gets read. Is there a way to make this pdf to readable pdf? I was able to make it searchable but that does not translate to readable as searchable text are still hidden and are not accessible. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't without some very serious code and documents that are the same. Images would have no concepts of structure like h1, h2 nor lists or tables. No idea what are pagination artifacts. Your task is nearly impossible if not totally impossible.